# A Fourier transform related problem.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

$\def\sgn{\operatorname{sgn}}$Given that $f(x)=\sgn(x)+\cos\pi x+\sin5\pi x (-1 \le x<1), g(x)=\alpha \cos\pi x+\beta \sin 5\pi x$ and $E(\alpha,\beta)=\int_{-1}^1|f(x)-g(x)|^2dx$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both real numbers, how can I express $E(\alpha,\beta)$ by using a quadratic function of $\alpha$ an $\beta$ ? Can somebody help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: $g(x)$ links to $E$. Could you type these directly in the question rather thank linking images?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I have edited the expression, please check.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
h(x) 
&:= 
f(x)-g(x)\\
&=
\text{sgn}(x)
+
(1-\alpha)\cos(\pi x)
+
(1-\beta)\sin(5\pi x)
\end{align*}

**Option 1**

If you compute the Fourier coefficients of $h$, then you can use [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) to evaluate the integral.

**Option 2**

Directly compute
\begin{align*}
h(x)^2
=& 
\text{sgn}(x)^2
+
(1-\alpha)^2\cos^2(\pi x)
+
(1-\beta)^2\sin^2(5\pi x)\\
&
+
2(1-\alpha)\text{sgn}(x)\cos(\pi x)
+
2(1-\beta)\text{sgn}(x)\sin(5\pi x)
+
2(1-\alpha)(1-\beta)\cos(\pi x)\sin(5\pi x)
\end{align*}

Since some of these terms ($\text{sgn}(x)\cos(\pi x)$ and $\cos(\pi x)\sin(5\pi x)$) are odd and we are integrating over a symmetric interval about 0,

\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^1 h(x)^2 dx
&=
\int_{-1}^1 
1
+
(1-\alpha)^2\cos^2(\pi x)
+
(1-\beta)^2\sin^2(5\pi x)
+
2(1-\beta)\text{sgn}(x)\sin(5\pi x)
dx
\end{align*}

Then split the integral into two pieces, corresponding to the intervals $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. Use trig identities to evaluate.

Comment: Thank you for providing two helpful options. I want to ask that for Parseval's equation, the integral interval is from -\infty to +\infty, does the equation still hold when the interval become -1 to +1?

Comment: You want the version for Fourier series of functions on an interval, not the one for the Fourier transform on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Thanks. By the way, shouldn't the cross-terms multiply by 2 in the second option?

Comment: @B.W.Zhang You are correct. Thank you.